# convert iso8601 date format to date object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[snippet of The date format received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23uhm.png) I want to display the date in an HTML table but unable to convert the iso8601 type date format to the date object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var startDate;
    var formattedDate;
    var day;


    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/employee/101",
            method: "Get",
            success: function(data,status){
                startDate = new Date(data.joinDate);
                day = startDate.dayOfWeek;
                console.log(startDate);
            }   
        });
    });
```

> I get error : invalid date at "console.log(startDate);"

I also need to increment the date but stuck at converting the iso8601 format to a normal date object.

Comment: What's `startDate.dayOfWeek` supposed to be? Please open console and see if there's some errors looking at you.

Comment: its is the day of week from the date.it is coming correctly.but 'startDate'is not accesible outside the function

Comment: No, sorry, you cannot get `.dayOfWeek` out of a Date object like you're doing. That's why I asked if console is throwing any errors...

Comment: .dayOfWeek is giving result

Comment: Where is `.joinDate` in your image / or / question? is it in this format? `YYYY-MM-DD` ?

Comment: I still don't get it... You have: `startDate = new Date(data.joinDate);` therefore IS a Date Object... Than you have `day = startDate.dayOfWeek;` Now, can you please do `console.log( day )` ? Do you really get a result?

Comment: I do get a result as 'Tuesday' which is correct.If I want to increment the date,how can I do it.Google suggests that iso8601 date format need to be converted to date object for doing it,which I am unable to attain.

Comment: Sorry, but 1: I don't see any snippet of your `joinDate` (either I know what's the supposed iso format), 2: using your exact code `day = startDate.dayOfWeek` throws `undefined`- either you say that it works.

Comment: If the answer doesn't work I'd like to point out a couple of things: `new Date().dayOfWeek` is undefined so `new Date().dayOfWeek()` will throw an error. The image of the response you are showing does not show `joinDate` that is the member you are trying to create a Date object from. So if you need any more help you at least need to post the value of `data.joinDate` or `JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have all it takes out of your `employee/101` data response:

[image]

```js
var data = {
  dayOfMonth: 14,
  monthValue: 11, // NOVEMBER, we need to -1 it since Date expects 0 based month value
  year: 2017,
}

var dateObject = new Date(data.year, data.monthValue - 1, data.dayOfMonth);

alert(dateObject)
```

On my locale:

> Tue Nov 14 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)

And BTW `startDate.dayOfWeek` given `startDate` is a Date object, you cannot use `dayOfWeek` like you did.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help.
I finally made it work as below:
I was able to display date, though I need a bit more modification to display day and month as ÝYY.But still I think it was good progress.

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var dateObj;

        $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/employee/101",
                method: "Get",
                success: function(data,status){

                    dateObj = new Date(data.joinDate.year,
                                       data.joinDate.monthValue - 1,
                                       data.joinDate.dayOfMonth);
                    console.log(dateObj);


                $('#timeTable th:not(:first-child)').each(function(){
                if($(this).attr('Id') === 'totalHours') return;
                $(this).text(dateObj.getDate()+'-'+dateObj.getMonth()+'-'+dateObj.getFullYear());
                dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + 1);
                }); 
            }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

my html table:

```
<table Id="timeTable" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Projects</th>
        <th id="mon" style="width:100px"></th>
        <th id="tue" style="width:100px"></th>
        <th id="wed" style="width:100px"></th>
        <th id="thu" style="width:100px"></th>
        <th id="fri" style="width:100px"></th>
        <th id="sat" style="width:100px"></th>
        <th id="sun" style="width:100px"></th>
        <th id="totalHours" style="width:100px"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Task1</td>
        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
        <td contenteditable='true'>2</td>
        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
        <td contenteditable='true'>3</td>
        <td contenteditable='true'>4</td>
        <td contenteditable='true'> </td>
        <td contenteditable='true'> </td>
        <td contenteditable='true'> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable='true'>Task2</td>
        <td contenteditable='true' >5</td>
        <td contenteditable='true' >2</td>
        <td contenteditable='true' >2.5</td>
        <td contenteditable='true' >3</td>
        <td contenteditable='true' >4</td>
        <td contenteditable='true' > </td>
        <td contenteditable='true' > </td>
        <td contenteditable='true' > </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Task3</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2.5</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```